# MvxImageViewLoader default image ignoring retina resources

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, mvvmcross, retina-display

I have a MvvmCross project that uses `MvxImageViewLoader` to load images from URLs in background. I'm using `DefaultImagePath` to specify the default image in case the URL is incorrect or no URL has been specified at all.

The issue is that this path is ignoring retina `@2x` images from the filesystem and always shows the non-retina image.

This is the code:

```
_imageLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => ImageView)
{
    // After loading the Image view, the scale of the image is always 1.0
    DefaultImagePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("image", "png")
};
// At this point, ImageView.Image.CurrentScale is 1.0 (WRONG) on retina devices
```

where `ImageView` is a standard `UIImageView`.

But loading the image from path directly works as expected:

```
// The scale of this image is 2.0 on retina devices (as expected)
var image = UIImage.FromFile(NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("image", "png"));
```

As a workaround, I added this conditional naming:

```
var imageName = UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale > 1 ? "image@2x" : "image";
_imageLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => ImageView)
{
    DefaultImagePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(imageName, "png")
};
// At this point, ImageView.Image.CurrentScale is 2.0 on retina devices as expected
```

But this doesn't take into account other naming conventions like `~ipad` for iPad and `@2x~ipad` for iPad retina. So I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or it's the MvvmCross plugin that should use the convenient `UIImage` initialization methods.

It seems that `MvxTouchLocalFileImageLoader`class [already uses `UIImage.FromFile`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/DownloadCache/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.Touch/MvxTouchLocalFileImageLoader.cs#L55), so I'm not sure why the behavior is different.

**EDIT:** Here's a [downloadable sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mh0y42qws5y95b5/RetinaImageDemo.zip) reproducing the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: If you just use `UIImage.FromFile` in some test code in your app, does it pick up the retina images correctly? If not, then try to solve that first - check the build actions, try a clean/rebuild, etc. If the test code does work, then I'm slightly stuck for ideas right now.

Comment: @Stuart the second piece of code is exactly that case and it works as expected.

Comment: @Stuart added sample project reproducing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [adding the prefix `res:` to the file path](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/DownloadCache/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.Touch/MvxTouchLocalFileImageLoader.cs#L23) makes  `MvxTouchLocalFileImageLoader` [to use `UIImage.FromFile`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/DownloadCache/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.Touch/MvxTouchLocalFileImageLoader.cs#L55) and otherwise [it reads the file to a `MemoryStream`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Plugins/Cirrious/DownloadCache/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.Touch/MvxTouchLocalFileImageLoader.cs#L39), ignoring any scale or device qualifier.

So, this now works as expected:

```
_imageLoader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => ImageView)
{
    DefaultImagePath = "res:" + NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(imageName, "png")
};
```

Not sure if this is the intended behavior or it is a bug in `MvxTouchLocalFileImageLoader` anyway.